# Could not find metadata org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter/maven-metadata.xml in local (D:\apache-maven-3.2.2\RepMaven)

Tags: java, maven

This problem occurred when refreshing maven when the global proxy was enabled. I tried the method in this article, but failed to solve the problem
https://www.cnblogs.com/wang-ze/p/13753010.html

I tried the method in this article, but failed to solve the problem
[博客园](https://www.cnblogs.com/wang-ze/p/13753010.html)

Comment: The usage of `RELEASE` as a version is wrong... better use a real version number for example `5.9.2` instead...